# Linear Regression problem in predicting values

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to predict values using linear regression . when I use [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XYWH.jpg)

```
reg.predict(60)
```

it pops like this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfGVW.jpg)

How to reshape this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prediction function takes a 2-D array as an input, so you can use `reg.predict([[60]])` instead